# Segmentation Fault Core Dump Error

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault, g++, coredump

This is my C program and I am using g++ compiler.
After compilation, when I run the code, it gives a segmentation fault (core dumped) error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

  FILE *fp;

  fopen("sample.txt", "w+");

  fprintf(fp, "%s %s %s %d", "We", "are", "in", 2016 );

  fclose(fp);

  return 0;
}
```

Please guide.

Comment: You are using `fp` without initializing it. That is cause for undefined behavior. Use `fp =   fopen("sample.txt", "w+");`.

Comment: Please delete your post. It's unlikely to be helpful to anybody else.

Answer (score 2):

Just found out:
Simply assign the file open function to my file descriptor.

```
fp = fopen("sample.txt", "w+");
```

Answer (score 0):

fprintf prints to the file given by the file pointer fp. In this case, fp is only declared and never assigned a value, hence is null. When fprintf uses the null pointer it causes a seg fault. You should have done fp = fopen(...)  so the pointer isn't null.

Comment: "hence is null" - it's *indeterminate*

Comment: You're totally right. For some reason  I was thinking fp was global